# Не работает Extract Text Plugin в Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, плагин, webpack4

В dist не добавляется файл со стилями

package.json

```
{
  "name": "jelly-effect",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Jelly Effect on Canvas",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "CreativeRusBear",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
let path = require('path'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

let conf = {
    entry: './src/js/script.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'./dist/js'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/js/'
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/styles.css'),
    ]
};

module.exports=(env, options)=>{
    let prod = options.mode === 'production';
    conf.devtool = prod ? 'source-map' : 'eval-sourcemap';
    return conf;
};
```

Comment: И не должен, ExtractTextPlugin не предназначен для Webpack 4, используйте https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

Comment: @andreymal Если установить бета версию, все работает (@next). Вчера тестил на другом проекте и все прекрасно работало

Comment: Не знаю, как у вас что-то работало, если в документации ExtractTextPlugin написано, что он не работает в Webpack 4

Comment: Но даже если допустить, что @next работает - почему бы не перейти на mini-css-extract-plugin?

Comment: @andreymal Это если не устанавливать бета-версию. Но я устанавливал так: `npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin@next  --save-dev`. Даже раздел в issue на github есть https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701

Comment: @andreymal стоит попробовать. Но хотелось бы все же решить эту проблему, раз этот плагин корректно работает :)

Comment: И да, совсем забыл спросить: что значит «не добавляется файл со стилями»? Всё собирается без ошибок, но файла нет?

Comment: @andreymal ага)

Comment: У меня с babel почему-то всё падает с ошибками (лень разбираться), а вот без babel файл `dist/js/css/style.css` появляется как положено согласно конфигу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема оказалась в версии css-loader (необходимо поставить v.0.28.11)

Поэтому кидаю [ссылку](https://gist.github.com/CreativeRusBear/b778f1914fe59db0a5aa6ec11b9fc809) на свой gist, в котором содержится готовый шаблон.

Comment: «"css-loader": "^0.28.11"» — протухший на два года... Вам бы всё же лучше обновить и его, и Babel 7 поставить, и mini-css-extract-plugin воткнуть)

Comment: @andreymal ох,ничего себе, спасибо большое за дельные советы, учту :)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо вам большое:) благодаря вашему комментарию, сравнил версии css-loader в вопросе и в ответе, и увидел, что там совсем разные версии, в этом и была проблема (уже протестил)